# Using word2vec pretrained vectors, how to generate ids of a sentence as input to tf.nn.embedding_lookup function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, word2vec

To extract the embedding representations of input data, the tensorflow documentation says we can use the following:

```
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, input_data)
```

Accdg to the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/embeddings#embedding_lookup), the 2nd parameter of the function tf.nn.embedding_lookup is a tensor of ids:

> ids: A Tensor with type int32 or int64 containing the ids to be looked up in params.

My question is: Given a sentence, say,

> "Welcome to the world"

how can I represent and transform it into `ids`? In the code below, how can I transform my sentence into `input_data`.

```
from gensim import models
embedding_path = "../embeddings/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin"
w = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format(embedding_path, binary=True)
X = w.syn0
W = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=X.shape),trainable=False, name="W")
embedding_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, X.shape)
embedding_init = W.assign(embedding_placeholder)
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_init, input_data)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(embed, feed_dict={embedding_placeholder: X})
```

Comment: You can simply map each word to a number and make the appropriate tensor. Haven't you seen the TensorFlow RNN tutorials?

Comment: Thanks @martianwars. I've seen that tutorial but it did not use word2vec from gensim instead it created it's own vocabulary from characters.

Comment: Here, I need to convert the sentence tokens into ids. These ids must corresponding to the word in the pretrained vector - if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a code something like this. I wasn't aware of the class attributes of `w` - couldn't find them in the gensim website.

```
s = "hello, how are you?"
tokens = tokenize(s)//function that returns a list of the tokens in a sentence

ids = []
for key in tokens:
  try:
    ids.append(w.vocab[key].index)
  except:
    ids.append(w.vocab['UNK'].index)
```

Comment: This actually shows power of gensim. Thank you for your post. If we had to create this index manually from raw embedding file, it would take longer.